# How can i link to attribute of an instance of a class

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

In an EA model I have a class. The class defines an attribute. I want to be able to have an instance of this class (an object) with the attribute visible on a diagram and the ability to link specifically to that attribute (as in the Link to Element Feature option).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You need to set the run state of the object

[image]

Once the following dialog is completed, it can look like

[image]

The value is free text and not linked to the original attribute, but better than nothing.

Comment: It is a new feature for me. It does not seem to solve the problem though.

Comment: First - I do not know any reasonable value to assign to each attribute, but it required. Second - I would have redeclare the attributes one by one. Third - it seems to be impossible to link a dependency specifically to that attribute via the Link to Element Feature option.

Comment: Well, this is the only option you got in EA. If you want more, send a feature request.

Comment: That is how you make instances and (instances of) attributes in EA. But I don't think you can use the "link to element feature" for those attribute instances. You could possibly use tagged values, but I'm not sure if the attribute instances have a ea_guid of their own to link to.

Comment: @GeertBellekens actually you _can_ create attributes in instances, but it seems more like a flaw in EA to allow that. You need to drag an existing attribute over the instance. But that's then some kind of zombie.