# Why cannot I connect an object (instance of a class) to a specific attribute of another object (instance of a class) in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a question regarding linking of elements to attributes:

Question: **Why cannot I connect an object (instance of a class) to a specific attribute of another object (instance of a class) in Enterprise Architect?**

I do not see any constraints in UML that would not allow me to do that. This is what I tried:

1. I know that I can link classes to a specific attribute of another class as shown in the following figure:

[image]

2. The end result will then look like this where I have a `Store` class connecting via two attributes `Manager` and `Deputy` to a `Person` class:

[image]

3. From there I can select the actual attribute to link to:

[image]

4. I also marked the attributes `containment` as `By Reference` to indicate that the value of the attributes should not be a scalar or simple value (shown as an asterisk next to the attribute):

[image]

5. But as soon as I create instances of the classes I cannot unambiguously connect the `Person` to the respective attributes of the `Store` instance:

[image]

6. This is because the `Link to Element Feature` does not allow me to select an `attribute`. Even, when I add an additional attribute to the `Store1` instance (`test` in my example) I cannot select that attribute from the list of attributes. So it is not clear, which of the two `Person` instances is actually the `Manager` and the `Deputy`.

[image]

Is there any explanation why this is not possible? Is this a bug? How are others trying to modell such a relationship?

Thanks for your advice! Regards, Ronald

Comment: I know this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611917. But in my question I am not going via "Set run state" but via "Link to Element feature". So in my opinion this is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of tying the connectors to actual `Attribute` of the instance (that have to be created manually as outlined in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732487/3881834)) we can also use an annotated connector where the the text of the connector by convention denotes its intended usage as shown in the following figure:

[image: Object instance with connections to two different instances of the same type with annotated connectors]

This has some advantates over the other solution:

1. No need for coding - everything can be done from via the UI
2. No need for custom sparx features (`Link to Element Feature`) - everything can be modeled via plain UML

One downside is similar to the other solution: in case the class name changes the connector annotation has to be updated as well. On the other hand, changing the name of the class is in my opinion less likely than changing an attribute name. Another disadvantage is that the whole mechanism depends on convention (`class.attribute`).

For me this works best as it is visually clear and the fastest way to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clue of @Thomas I realised that I could redefine the attributes on the object instance in order to be able to connect them to another object instance.

With the script lines below I now can easily recreate the all attributes on the object instance:

```
$objectId = '{F4DB0F04-18D4-4acb-BA1D-FF55813D7559}'

$object = $ea.GetElementByGuid($objectId);

$classifier = $ea.GetElementById($object.ClassifierID);

$attrsByRef = $classifier.Attributes |? Containment -eq 'By Reference'

$attrsByRef | Select Name, AttributeGuid

Name    AttributeGUID                         
----    -------------                         
Manager {614E5483-2E06-4070-AFB7-B4EDB4A981A7}
Deputy  {82403A08-5E2A-4e68-B39A-6220C889C6E9}

foreach($attr in $attrsByRef) 
{ 
    $objattr = $object.Attributes.AddNew($attr.Name, $attr.Type); 
    $objattr.ClassifierID = $attr.ClassifierID; 
    $objattr.Update(); 
}
```

I can then use the standard `link to element feature` from the UI or via `StyleEx` from the API to connect the Person instances with the correct attribute:

[image: Object with Attributes]

In the project browser I can now see the attributes under the object:

[image: Project Browser View]

This is certainly not an ideal solution, but in my opinion still better that to use associations to model each single attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: An instance does not have attributes. None at all. You can show values for instantiated attributes, but that's not the same. For that simple reason you can not link connectors.

Linking to features is a Sparx feature and not UML standard. You might send a feature (huh, so many features here) request to Sparx to support what you wish.

Anyhow, you can use `Pin End(s)` from the context menu. This will fix one (or both) end(s) of the connector ends to where you want it.

Comment: Hi @Thomas. I tried the pinning option but unfortunately this only gives me a visual indicator of the intention of the connector. Furthermore when the element pinned to resizes, the connector will not stick to the position. I however managed to add attributes to an object instance and from there I could use the `link to element feature` option. I will answer below with some additional images for illustration. thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Ronald

Comment: Yes, I know. It is not a replacement for the other feature. But it's the only way you can achieve a similar behavior - just that you need to adapt it when resizing the element.